# IE: When clicking Google +1 a new window opens and then tries to close again

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, google-plus-one

I have recently introduced some Google +1 buttons to my site.

I am calling the button like this:

```
<g:plusone size="small" 
      count="false" 
      callback="plusone_vote" 
      href='http://www.mysite.com'>
</g:plusone>
```

The plusone_vote callback is a js function which pushes a tracking event to Google Analytics.

This works for the majority of users. However, a small number are getting an issue. When they click on the +1 link a new IE window appears and then displays the message

> "The webpage you're viewing is trying to close this window.
>   Do you want to close this window?"

If the user clicks "No" they get they Google +1 privacy page ("I'm fine with Google using my +1's and other info around content and ads on non-Google websites"). They can then click the "Share my +1's button" and the window closes. However, they "+1" action never appears to happen. The button does not turn blue and the page does not show up in their profile.

The users were all using IE8 or IE9 on Windows 7 - a combination which works fine for most users. The only thing that appears to be the same is that they all use the same type of laptop - I'm struggling to see the significance of that though.

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure you have 3rd party cookies enabled: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/V5bl-S4G_-E

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue is with your IE security settings: the page MUST be displayed as a regular 'internet' webpage in order for IE to correctly run the +1 and Facebook Like plugins without this error message.

In order to fix this:

1. Go into Internet Options in the IE menu
2. Go to Security Settings.  Click on 'local intranet'.
3. Click on sites.  Make sure 'detect local intranet' and all it's sub checkboxes are unchecked.  Go into 'advanced' and make sure your webpage's domain is not listed.  Close this window.
4. Now, click on 'Trusted Sites' and then 'Sites'.  Make sure to remove your site's domain if it's listed.

All sites which are not 'Intranet' or a 'Trusted Site' default to public internet settings, which is the same as what your users will see (unless you're writing a business application which runs for internal network users, I suppose).  This should fix this pop up, and allow +1 and Facebook like plugins to function correctly.